# Assign pathnames returned from bash command(s) to an AppleScript list

Tags: bash, applescript

I want to prompt the paths of the 10 recently added files of a directory (recursively) in Applescript as a list. This works fine in bash:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

array=(`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -n 10`)

echo "${array[*]}"

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

I’d like to store the resulting array in an Applescript Variable:

```
set l to (do shell script "______________")
```

How can I put the bash part into a working 1-liner? Maybe there is also an Applescript-only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you *"shell out"* from AppleScript the `class` of the value that you assign to a variable, (i.e. the variable named `l` in your example), will always be [text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCIAHJF) and *not* a [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE).

In your scenario you're essentially capturing the pathname(s) that the [find](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) utility etc send to `stdout` (fd 1) which Applescript just recognizes as `text`.

To convert each line (i.e. a *pathname* that is printed to `stdout` via your bash commands) you'll need to utilize a helper [subroutine/function](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH) as shown in the following gist.

```
  set stdout to do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of "/absolute/path/to/target/directory" & " -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -n 10"

  set latestList to transformStdoutToList(stdout)

  -- Test it's a proper AppleScript list.
  log class of latestList
  log (item 1 of latestList)
  log (item 2 of latestList)
  -- ...

  (**
   * Transforms each line printed to stdout to form a new list of pathnames.
   *
   * Pathname(s) may contain newline `\n` characters in any part, including
   * their basenames. Below we read each line, if it begins with a forward
   * slash `/` it is considered to be the start of a pathname. If a line does
   * not begin with a forward slash `/` it is considered to be part of the
   * prevous pathname. In this scenario the line is appended to previous item
   * of the list and the newline character `\n` is reinstated.
   *
   * @param {String} pathsString - The pathname(s) printed to stdout.
   * @return {List} - A list whereby each item is a pathname.
   *)
  on transformStdoutToList(pathsString)
    set pathList to {}
    repeat with aLine in paragraphs of pathsString
        if aLine starts with "/" then
            set end of pathList to aLine
        else
            set last item of pathList to last item of pathList & "\n" & aLine
        end if
    end repeat
    return pathList
  end transformStdoutToList
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. In the first line reading:

   ```
   set stdout to do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of "/absolute/path/to/target/directory" & " -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -n 10"
   ```

   - we utilize AppleScript's [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command to execute your bash commands.
   - Assign the result of the bash commands (which is typically a multi-line string of *pathnames*) to the AppleScript variable named `stdout`. The class of the value assigned to `stdout` will be `text` - you can verify this by temporarily adding the following line to the script:

     ```
     log class of stdout
     ```
   - **Note:** You'll need to redefine the part that currently reads; `/absolute/path/to/target/directory`, with a real absolute path to the directory/folder that you want to search. You'll also notice that this target *pathname* is preceded with `& quoted form of` - this just ensures any space character(s) in the given *pathname* are interpreted correctly.
2. The second line reading:

   ```
   set latestList to transformStdoutToList(stdout)
   ```

   invokes the `transformStdoutToList` subroutine passing in the value of `stdout` and assigns the result returned to the variable named `latestList`. The class of the value assigned to `latestList` will be `list`. Again, you can verify this by temporarily adding the following line to the script:

   ```
   log class of latestList
   ```
3. The `transformStdoutToList` subroutine transforms each line (i.e. a *pathname*) that is passed to it and forms a new `list` of *pathname(s)*. Please read the comments in the code above for further explanation - you'll notice that is successfully handles any *pathname(s)* that may include newline character(s).

---

**Additional Note:**

The aforementioned `transformStdoutToList` subroutine includes a line that reads:

```
set last item of pathList to last item of pathList & "\n" & aLine
```

The `"\n"` part exists to reinstate any newline characters that may exist in a *pathname*. However when you compile the script in the *AppleScript Editor* this will appear as follows:

```
set last item of pathList to last item of pathList & "
" & aLine
```

<sub>**Note:** the newline character, i.e. the `\n` part, has disappeared and has created an actual line-break.</sub>

***This is normal and the script will produce the expected result***. However, if you want to preserve the `"\n"` part in your *AppleScript Editor* then please change your preferences as described below:

1. Select `AppleScript Editor` > `Preferences...` from the menu bar.
2. Select the `Editing` tab.
3. Click the checkbox for the `Formatting: Escape tabs and line breaks in strings` (i.e. switch this option on).

---

**Edit:**

> How can I put the bash part into a working **1-liner**

If you *must* have a *"1-liner"* and are willing to sacrifice readability then you could do something like this instead:

```
set l to transformStdoutToList(do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of "/absolute/path/to/target/directory" & " -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -n 10")
```

However, you'll still need to utilize the aforementioned `transformStdoutToList` subroutine, so that will need to be present in your script too.