# Rename all files of the same extension within subfolders of a directory using apple script?

Tags: applescript, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a directory full of folders whose subfolders each contain a .xml file. They are all supposed to be named apple.xml but unfortunately, they each have different names such as apple_1.xml or appleTEST.xml and other unique variations that don't follow a specific pattern. Luckily, there is only one .xml file per folder.

I was hoping there was a way to use Applescript to search an entire directory and all of its folders for files with the .xml extension and rename them all to just apple.xml?

Thanks

Comment: I'd just do it from **Terminal** using the following _compound command_, `IFS=; while read -r f; do echo mv -v "$f" "${f%/*}/apple.xml"; done <<< "$(find "/path/to/parent_XML_dir" -type f -iname '*.xml')"` while changing `"/path/to/parent_XML_dir"` to the proper pathname. Run it the first time still with the `echo` _command_ in front of the `mv` _command_ to see what the `mv` _command_ would look like. If you like the output, remove the `echo` _command_ and run it again to rename the files. **NOTE: Always insure you have a backup before running _commands_ that modify the filesystem!**

Comment: @user3439894 - That fails when part of a pathname includes a newline character(s). See [how to find & safely handle file names containing newlines](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020). Use the `-print0` option with [`find`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) to ensure each pathname is delimited with a NUL byte (`\0`) before redirecting to a `while` loop. To read the NUL char in a `while` loop add the `-d ''` option to `read`. E.g.: `while IFS= read -rd '' f; do echo mv -v "$f" "${f%/*}/apple.xml"; done < <(find "/path/to/parent_XML_dir" -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0)`

Comment: Demo: **1.** Create test files, run: `mkdir -p ~/Desktop/foo/{a..c} && touch ~/Desktop/foo/{a..b}/apple_1.xml && touch ~/Desktop/foo/c/$'apple\napple.xml'` - note in folder `c` the multi-line filename. **2.** Run your cmd: `IFS=; while read -r f; do mv -v "$f" "${f%/*}/apple.xml"; done <<< "$(find ~/Desktop/foo -type f -iname '*.xml')"` - note, the file in  folder c` has not been renamed. **3.** Clean up, run  `rm -rf ~/Desktop/foo` and repeat point 1. **4.** Run `while IFS= read -rd '' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f%/*}/apple.xml"; done < <(find ~/Desktop/foo -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0)`

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript code is pretty much self-explanatory and should work for you.

```
-- Choose Parent Folder To Search For .xml Files
set searchFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder)

-- Get Paths Of All .xml Files In The Parent Folder And All Sub Folders
set xmlFiles to do shell script "find " & (quoted form of searchFolder) & " -name *.xml"

-- Create A List From The Result
set xmlFiles to paragraphs of xmlFiles as list

-- Loops Through The List And Renames Each File
repeat with i in xmlFiles
    tell application "System Events" to set name of disk item i to "apple.xml"
end repeat
```

Comment: There is no real need to shell out (`do shell script ...`) to the `find` _command_ and then have to parse its output or run a loop (`repeat with ...`) on its parsed output to take action on each file individually If one has to shell out to `find`, one might as well just do it from **Terminal** as the necessary _command_ is already in the comment to the OP from yesterday. Also, the parentheses around `(quoted form of searchFolder)` **are not necessary**.

Comment: @wch1zpink - **Tip**: be cautious of using `set xmlFiles to paragraphs of xmlFiles as list` when wanting to assign each pathname, (i.e. what the `find` utility prints to `stdout`),  to an item in an AppleScript `list`. Any pathname containing a newline character(s) `\n` will create multiple list `items` instead of one. To improve the robustness of your program use a custom subroutine, such as the one named `transformStdoutToList` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358282/assign-pathnames-returned-from-bash-commands-to-an-applescript-list/56362996#56362996).

Answer (score 1):

Because you've stated there is only one **XML** file in each *sub folder*, it makes it extremely easy and quick to do with **AppleScript**.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do as you've asked, after you select the **Parent XML Folder** when prompted, by running this *code* in, e.g., **Script Editor**.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set xmlFilesList to a reference to ¬
        (every file of entire contents of ¬
            (choose folder with prompt "Please Select Parent XML Folder:") ¬
                whose name extension is "xml")
    set name of xmlFilesList to "apple.xml"
end tell
```

This *example* **AppleScript** *code* is simple and fast in execution, and providing you select the proper **Parent XML Folder** there should not be any issues. **NOTE: Always insure you have a backup before running commands that modify the filesystem!**

Comment: Nice choice using the `reference to` operator.  Funny thing is I actually considered and wondered to myself if I were to reference the files, would I be able to rename them all in one shot without using a loop. Without even trying I figured it would throw an error so I didn’t even try LOL.  +1 . Also, Script Debugger automatically inserted the parentheses which you mentioned

Comment: @wch1zpink, I have to admit that CJK got me using `a reference to` in some of my personal _scripts_, and when I saw in the OP there was only one XML file in each sub folder I figured this was a perfect time to use it. Yesterday I posted to the OP to suggest using Terminal as I'm able to write that off the top of my head and wasn't on a Mac (was on a Linux box) where I could test it before posting it. Today I'm back on a Mac. Oh, Script Debugger is the culprit, well they are not technically needed in Script Editor or Automator. Maybe it's being done to make it look pretty. Thanks for the +1!